# Invalid operands for multiplication when piping two SCSS functions

Tags: html, css, sass, compass-sass

I'm working on SASS unit-conversion function, and i have defined two functions:

```
convert-units(...);
strip-units(...);
```

Both work perfectly fine separately, until i pipe one in another, like this:

```
strip-units( convert-units(...) );
```

the result is following error:

```
invalid operands for multiplication on line 68 at column 23
```

I tried to copy manually result from convert-units() into strip-units(), and it it works correctly.

Here is the working example:
http://sassmeister.com/gist/b5c61fc7baec1e3bec1f
Please scroll to the bottom until you find commented `pipe: strip-units(...` fragment.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the line `$pxValue / $size + $outputUnit` actually does not create a number with a unit, but a string which looks exactly the same. There is no easy way to add a unit to a number in sass, but I found an answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356899/is-it-possible-to-add-a-dynamic-unit-to-a-unitless-number-in-sass) (there's also a little bit more background about why there is no easy way):

```
@function length($number, $unit) {
  $strings: 'px' 'cm' 'mm' '%' 'ch' 'pica' 'in' 'em' 'rem' 'pt' 'pc' 'ex' 'vw' 'vh' 'vmin' 'vmax';
  $units:   1px  1cm  1mm  1%  1ch  1pica  1in  1em  1rem  1pt  1pc  1ex  1vw  1vh  1vmin  1vmax;
  $index: index($strings, $unit);

  @if not $index {
    @warn "Unknown unit `#{$unit}`.";
    @return false;
  }

  @return $number * nth($units, $index);
}
```

Then simply do `$outputValue: length($pxValue / $size,  $outputUnit);` and it works.

See [my gist](https://gist.github.com/doits/0e02176e9956b1029963) (I failed to make SassMeister save my updated code, don't know why)

Comment: Amazing you dig into this question! I have found the same issue, `10 + px` is not the same as `10 * 1px`, i have modified my equations after that, and came with a simpler solution http://sassmeister.com/gist/c5aa6c3dbaf2aa0917ac but since i tested your answer and it's working too I can accept it :-)

Comment: No Problem, and simpler is always better, that is for sure :-)

Comment: Ok, I have written some tests for unit conversions, and in some cases Your solution performs better, so I will keep with it. I think this may be useful in a part of a bigger tool I'm working on. Final version (probably) http://sassmeister.com/gist/026353b7d219c8e9b61a